# WooCommerce remove product from a category programmatically based on date creation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way of removing a WooCommerce product from a certain category after 30 days?

So when I add a new product, I check the 'whats-new' category. Then after 30 days, I would like that to automatically be removed from that category, as it's no longer new.

I have a bit of code that can assess how old the product is, but then I don't really know how to work the rest.... and do I add this in my 'content-product.php'?

```
<?php
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

    $newness_days = 30;
    $created = strtotime( $product->get_date_created() );
    if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created ) {

        // if is new do nothing

   } else {

       // it's old, 

   }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: you can make custom hook for that

Comment: How do I do that Ariful?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: `wp_remove_object_terms( $product_id, $cat_ids, 'product_cat' );`

From this [StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710304/woocommerce-remove-product-from-category).